# execlp behaving strangely

Tags: c, unix, arguments, exec

I am attempting to run a very simple program with fork and execlp, but it does not work as I would expect. 
I presently have a file in my working directory simply named '1'. So the command **rm 1*** should remove it. However when tried via execlp, it does not.

```
int main()
{

  if(fork()==0)
    {
      execlp("rm", "rm", "1*",  NULL);
      perror("Problem\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you check the return value/errno? For errno interpretation: http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp

Comment: Filename expansion is a shell feature. rm is trying to remove a file called '1*'.

Comment: execlp cetainly runs, it claims that 1* can not be found. Even though 1 is clearly sitting right there in the directory.

Comment: @user1775655 It says `1*` is not found, not `1`. Your command is equivalent to running `rm 1\*` from the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, you want:

```
execlp("sh", "sh", "rm 1*", (char *)0);
```

Note that this is a rather bad idea, from the standpoints of security, robustness, and efficiency. If you want to remove files matching a pattern, you should do this directly in C. It's easy with the `glob` function and a simple loop.